# Merge arrays in foreach

Tags: php, arrays, session, foreach, merge

Need some help, I want to merge some arrays **($values)** from $_SESSION in one array **($result)**.

The code below **doesn't** work:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $product => $values){
  $result = array_merge($result,$values);
}
```

If i print $result out, it only add the first array, but not the second.

```
array(5) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(14) "Produkt1"
  ["quantity"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

It should be like this:

```
array(5) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(14) "Produkt1"
  ["quantity"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["name"]=>
  string(26) "Produkt2"
  ["quantity"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

The $_SESSION looks like this:

```
array(1) {
       ["cart_item"]=>
       array(2) {
        ["Produkt1"]=>
        array(5) {
          ["name"]=>
          string(14) "Produkt1"
          ["quantity"]=>
          string(1) "1"
        }
        ["Produkt2"]=>
        array(5) {
          ["name"]=>
          string(26) "Produkt2"
          ["quantity"]=>
          string(1) "1"
        }
      }
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: And how do you expect __same__ keys in array to work? `$result['name']` will show you what? `Produkt1`? `Produkt2`?

Comment: Your "it should be like this" is not possible, that's not how arrays work.

Answer (score 0):

Your desired outcome is impossible (as outlined in the comments), but you could think about either creating `unique keys` for each product, or a `nested array` per product:

```
$arr = [
   "cart_item" => [
      "Produkt1" => [
         "name" => "Produkt1",
         "quantity" => "1"
      ],
      "Produkt2" => [
         "name" => "Produkt2",
         "quantity" => "1"
      ]
   ]
];


// create unique keys for each product using a counter
foreach ($arr['cart_item'] as $key => $value) {
   $count++;
   foreach ($value as $key => $value) {
      $key .= $count;
      $arr0[$key] = $value;
   }
}

// create nested array for each product record
$count = 0;
foreach ($arr['cart_item'] as $key => $value) {
   foreach ($value as $key => $value) {
      $arr1[$count][$key] = $value;
   }
   $count++;
}
```

working [demo](https://3v4l.org/Gll6o)